# Cómo Reducir el número de operadores condicionales (4) utilizados en la expresión (máximo permitido 3)

Tags: java, sonar

Estoy usando `sonarqube` para mejorar y optimizar el código, pero no he podido resolver este error:

```
 return response != null && !(response.getIdSegmento() == null ||

response.getIdModelo() == null || response.getPuntaje() == null ||

response.getProductos() == null);
```

Necesito reducir los operadores lógicos a 3.

Comment: response.isValid()

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion muy elegante es usar el api de validaciones de Java.

Si tu proyecto no incluye ya la dependencia o te dan error los imports puedes agregarla mediante las coordenadas

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Si usas hibernate adicionalmente deberas agregar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Tu clase quedara algo asi:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;


public class Response{

@NotNull //sin parametros
int idSegmento;
@NotNull("el ID de modelo no puede estar vacio") // mensaje de error en caso de no cumplisrse esta validacions
int getIdModelo;
@NotNull
double getPuntaje;
@NotNull
List<Producto> productos;
@NotNull
@NotEmpty("El nombre no puede estar vacio")
@Size(min = 10, max = 200, message 
  = "El nombre debe de estar entre 10 y 200 caracteres")
String nombre;
@Email(message = "El correo electronico no es valido")
private String email;
}
```

La documentacion javadoc de todas las anotaciones esta en https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html

El tutorial oficial de Oracle lo hallas en https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm